# How to reduce Apache Storm tuple transfer latency

Tags: azure, apache-storm, latency, azure-hdinsight

I'm building a large scale query processing system, which require small latency (  ideally < 1s per request ). I'm using Storm but found that a tuple takes about **300ms** from emitted from upstream bolts to received by downstream bolts.

Any ideas on how to reduce this latency?

PS: I'm using HDInsight Storm service in Azure, 4 datanotes with default settings.

Answer (score 1):

The latency may be cause due to network data transfer. To reduce latency you can try to merge some bolt logic if that is possible (for instance filter bolt may be merge with a tokenizer bolt).

Another idea, is to use the LocalorShuffle grouping on your streams so that storm sends tuples to tasks in the same worker process.

Finally, you may tune the  message buffers for optimizing the performance of your topology.

Here is an excellent article about the internal buffers :
[understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/06/21/understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers/)

Comment: Also new A8 and A9 are network optimized, so this might be a solution too. See here http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/hdinsight/